# How can I control Internet Explorer with Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, internet-explorer

Is it possible to control progammatically Internet Explorer with Perl and have each opened instance of IE  configured to use different proxy?

Could someone provide code example or point to some CPAN module which do that?

Comment: You mean, you want to run IE on server side? Does it have to be Perl? If yes, why?

Answer (score 3):

While it is entirely possible to control Internet Explorer via Perl using a variety of means (using [Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aIE%3a%3aMechanize) or accessing the [IBrowser2 and related interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752042%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) via [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aOLE)), I am doubtful your requirement of running multiple instances with different proxies can be met.

Answer (score 0):

Look up [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

This is a browser-automation tool, commonly used for testing web sites.

It can integrate into Perl. (see http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#programming-languages)